# Multiplayer APIs in Google Play Games Services will no longer be available. How to migrate to Firebase?

Tags: google-api, google-play-games, multiplayer

I have published my app ("Match4app") recently with multiplayer feature, after months of hard working, using the Multiplayer APIs in Google Play Games Services.

Now, I received an email from Google:

*Real-time multiplayer in Play Game Services is going away on March 31, 2020.
We’d like to inform you that on March 31, 2020, the real-time and turn-based multiplayer APIs in Google Play Games Services will no longer be available.
Action required
Because some of your games use one or both of these APIs (listed below), you’ll need to find replacements in order to continue offering multiplayer experiences. Migration options include using Firebase Realtime Database for multiplayer hosting and Google Cloud OpenMatch for matchmaking. You can log into your Cloud account to use Firebase Realtime Database for free with the Spark Plan.
We know this change requires extra work on your part, and we thank you for your understanding. If you have any questions or concerns, please let us know by filling out.*

Questions:

- How difficult is this "extra work" to migrate my game to "Firebase Realtime Database" and "Google Cloud OpenMatch" ?
- Is there any tutorial with simple step-by-step instructions such as "1. replace mGoogleSignInClient.silentSignIn() with "FirebaseSignInBlaBlaBla... 2.replace this by this,  etc." ?
- If there is no simple migration and this requires an implementation from the scratch, is there any tutorial to make a multiplayer game with "Firebase Realtime Database" and "Google Cloud OpenMatch" ?
- This "Spark Plan" seems to be free. However, this comes with limitations according to this link:
  https://firebase.google.com/pricing/?hl=vi

  Simultaneous connections: 100.

  Is there any other "free" alternative, similar to the deprecated Google APIs ?

Answer (score 1):

Answers:

1. There's lots of work to do. It's a re-write from scratch.
2. No. You still need to sign in, but you need to do a whole lot of OAuth stuff in order
   to authorise your client via Google Play Services and your Firebase database.
3. There's a few youtube videos on it, but they always go the easy route of providing random opponents. None of them provide a player search if you want to play against a certain opponent (like GPG used to do).
4. Not that I could see. I'm moving our game to random players as there seems to be no real solution. Google Cloud OpenMatch seems very nebulous. I can't work out if it's a backend only, or whether I have to install it on my own server.